# remote user leave event is not working in webrtc video

Tags: webrtc

I want to get notification when user leave the room , or close the browser, then i should get that notification for that i tried this 2 function but that is not working

```
    pc.removestream= (event) => {
                    console.log("user removed");
                  }
stream.onremovetrack = ({track}) => {
                        console.log(`${track.kind} track was removed.`);
                        if (!stream.getTracks().length) {
                          console.log(`stream ${stream.id} emptied (effectively removed).`);
                        }
                    };
```

here i have placed my whole code for webrtc, can anyone please check my code and help me to resolve this issue ?

```
pc.ontrack = ({track, streams: [stream]}) => {  


                    stream.onremovetrack = ({track}) => {
                        console.log(`${track.kind} track was removed.`);
                        if (!stream.getTracks().length) {
                          console.log(`stream ${stream.id} emptied (effectively removed).`);
                        }
                    };
                    remoteVideo1.srcObject = stream;  
              };

              pc.removestream= (event) => {
                console.log("user removed");
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

A user closing their browser is equivalent to `pc.close()`, not removal of any stream or tracks.

The best way to detect this is to create a data channel and check its [closed](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCSctpTransportState.closed) state ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/s3c5uu5y/)):

```
const dc = pc.createDataChannel("", {negotiated: true, id: 0});
...
dc.onclose = () => console.log("user left");
```

The remote browser sends an [SCTP ABORT](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dfn-close-the-connection) chunk over the wire in this case, making it distinguishable from a network drop.